# На что влияет добавление кастомных атрибутов в тегах?

Tags: html

В процессе разработки очень удобно передавать некие данные в кастомных атрибутах тега.

```
<input kclass="castom\themes\tools\blocks\MainPage\MKLoginEditText" class=" form-control" placeholder="логин или email" name="nick" load_content="root_content">
```

Влияет ли на что-то добавления и использование кастомных атрибутов? Например, важно ли это для поисковиков и тд и тп.

Answer (score 2):

Добавление кастомных аттрибутов делает ваш html невалидным, однако вы можете добавить `custom data attribute` согласно спецификации `html5`:

```
<div data-attr="value"></div>
```

[3.2.5.7. Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)